# ES6: Why does my misplacement of the parenthesis still produce same result?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I noticed that I had a type in one of my forEach statements but I still got the same result.

```
foo = ["bobby", "tommy", "brendan"]

foo.forEach((f => {
    console.log(f)
}))

vs. 

foo.forEach((f) => {
    console.log(f)
})
```

I'm curious as to why the result would be the same on the first one, which I made the typo on.

Comment: `forEach` accepts one argument - putting `()`s around an argument won't change anything, and functions with a single parameter don't require parentheses

Comment: Cause Braces for 1 argument is optional in Es6. So in first case you are just wrapping your function inside extra braces. Nothing wrong there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An arrow function with one argument can be written in two ways:

```
f => {
    console.log(f)
}
```

And

```
(f) => {
    console.log(f)
}
```

So the braces around the argument part are optional if there is only one argument.

And placing braces around a complete expression does not change anything for that expression, this:

```
f => {
    console.log(f)
}
```

and this

```
(f => {
    console.log(f)
})
```

or even this

```
((f => {
    console.log(f)
}))
```

is identical.

Your first code block can be formatted as this for a better understanding:

```
foo.forEach(
   // first argument of forEach
   (f => {
      console.log(f)
   })
   // end of argument list of forEach
)
```

So there are no misplaced braces, you just removed the optional ones around the `f` and place optional once around the complete expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo.forEach((f => {
    console.log(f)
}))
```

`forEach` accepts two paramters(first is method/function and second is optional which value to use as `this` object when executing callback), wrapping it around with `()` is not required. Although with arrow functions, if you have a single parameter you don't need to explicity wrap it with `()`, but you need to wrap you arguments if your method has multiple arguments.

You can check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) out for further reading on arrow functions and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for `forEach` in js